# How to get the brightness percentage in Android?

Tags: java, android, brightness

I am trying to get the brightness value from Android (12) and converting it to percentage using

```
android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver().SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS)
```

Now, when brightness is at 0% brightness value is at 1.0 and at 100% brightness value is at 255.0. However, when the brightness is at 50%, the value returned is 22.0. This makes me think the brightness value is logarithmic.

Is there a method to convert this or get this value as percentage?

Comment: Did you search the web for "android screen_brightness logarithmic"? I found a web page describing exactly what you are looking for with code and all.

Comment: Explanation and interesting lookup table approach is found here: https://tunjid.medium.com/reverse-engineering-android-pies-logarithmic-brightness-curve-ecd41739d7a2

Comment: The method used in the website relies on a brightness slider in the app, however I want to get the brightness value directly from the settings

Answer (score 4):

I have found an approximate solution. Unfortunately, there is no direct way to get access to the linear brightness values through an API in Android.

However, there is a way to approximate it. Note that this issue occurs on devices past Android 9 using a logarithmic brightness curve (Pixel devices for example).

To get the approximate brightness value:

1. Get the brightness with

> android.provider.Settings.System.getFloat(context.getContentResolver().SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS)

2. Copy the [Mathutils file](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/util/MathUtils.java;drc=dc7efaec81b564f1b0fbabca25ca694755986db6;l=27) used in the android source code into your project directory
3. Copy the convertLinearToGammaFloat() function found in AOSP source code [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/src/com/android/settingslib/display/BrightnessUtils.java;l=129?q=convertLinearToGammaFloat&sq=) into your class and pass the parameters into it. **val** will be the brightness value you got from the first step, **min** will be 0.0f, **max** will be 255.0f (in case of Pixel devices).
4. Copy the getPercentage() function from AOSP source code [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/display/BrightnessLevelPreferenceController.java;bpv=1;bpt=1?q=Brightness%20getPercentage()&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject). Pass in the value got from convertLinearToGammaFLoat() into **value**.**min** and **max** will be the **GAMMA_SPACE_MIN** and **GAMMA_SPACE_MAX** variables found   [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/src/com/android/settingslib/display/BrightnessUtils.java;drc=dc7efaec81b564f1b0fbabca25ca694755986db6;bpv=1;bpt=1;l=24)

The value received from getPercentage() will be the approximate brightness percentage value. There is around 3% margin of error for this which you can account for by subtracting it from the total brightness if it is within a certain range.

Comment: if You want brightness between 0 - 1 then change the 12 value to 1 in convertlineartogammaFloat() method

Comment: How do you identify the max value for different phones? Like 255.0f for Pixel?
How can I do this for Samsung / OPlus, etc?

Comment: That's very helpful. It works quite well on my Nokia 7.2. However, we don't know the minimum and maximum values on the different phones. As one can see in https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/display/BrightnessLevelPreferenceController.java the method BrightnessLevelPreferenceController is using the PowerManager class to retrieve that info. However, that's not publicly available :-(